# Unix timestamp to datetime string

Tags: code-golf, date

Given a unix timestamp as an input, give a datetime string, in a format like so: "YYMMDD.HHmm"

### Rules

- The input is a number (integer) of a millisecond-precise UNIX epoch time (milliseconds since 1970 January 1st 00:00:00.000 UTC).
- The values must be padded with zeroes if they are 1 character instead of 2. (e.g.: for "DD", "1" is not acceptable, but "01" is.)
- The output must be a single string. No arrays.
- Leap second handling doesn't matter.
- Shortest wins.

Good luck!

### Example

```
Input: 1547233866744
Output: 190111.1911
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice challenge, but there are a few clarifications to be made. To make the challenge self-contained, you should probably explain what the Unix epoch is. Additionally, what should be done with leap seconds? What should be done with the Year 2038 problem?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Edited the post to explain what the Unix epoch is. Leap second implementation doesn't matter, since the output string is not second-precise. The Year 2038 problem doesn't currently matter since it could be a limitation of the running device or the chosen programming language.

Comment: Does the timezone matter?

Comment: I take it the year is represented by a two digit number?

Comment: Can you add a few more test cases?

Comment: @skiilaa the leap second could still cause the minute to “tick” over. If you give a value that’s 5s away from a minute, and someone doesn’t handle the leap seconds correctly, they could calculate a value in the next minute...

Comment: Are builtins allowed? Because if not, the only valid and completely correct programs are probably on the order of millions of characters. See here why timezones and time special cases cause madness: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer no.

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance yes.

Comment: @Tim it doesn't matter.

Comment: @FabianRöling timezones don't matter.

Comment: What range of times stamps need to work = can we drop timestamps before year 2000?

Comment: @chux, See rule #1.

Comment: @Shaggy Rulle #1 describes the offset and scale of the time stamp - not the acceptable range.  The range certainly can be thought of as _from 0 upward_, but the requirement for a 2 digit year implies an alternate range may be acceptable, as in timestamps of 20xx.  IAC, I was hoping to here from OP.

Comment: @chux just get the last two digits of the year count

Comment: @skiilaa, Yes, well understand the desire output format of 2 digits, but over what _range_?  Is 2000-2099 sufficient? Or are  years before 2000, after 2099 needed?

Comment: @chux literally get the last two characters of the full year converted to a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [v1.4.5](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5), <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```
GîÐU s3)¤o>J i.G
```

1 byte saved thanks to [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/oliver), which led to another 2 bytes saved.

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=R+7QVSBzMymkbz5KIGkuRw==&input=MTU0NzIzMzg2Njc0NA==)

---

### Explanation

```
GîÐU s3)¤o>J i.G
                     :Implicit input of integer U
G                    :16
 î                   :Get the first 16 characters of the following string
  ÐU                 :  Convert U to a date object
     s3              :  Convert to ISO string
       )             :End get
        ¤            :Slice off the first 2 characters
         o           :Filter
          >J         :  Greater than -1
             i.G     :Insert "." at 0-based index 16, with wrapping
```

---

### Notes / Tips

- Getting the first 16 characters of the ISO string and *then* slicing off the first two is [a byte shorter than performing a single slice](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=0FUgczMpczJHIG8+SiBpLkc=&input=MTU0NzIzMzg2Njc0NA==).
- `G` is used to insert the `.` at the required index because [using a literal `6` would cause it to be combined with the `.` and for that to be interpreted as a decimal that would be inserted at the start of the string](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=R+7QVSBzMymkbz5KIGkuNg==&input=MTU0NzIzMzg2Njc0NA==). To get around that I'd need to [add a `'` before the `.` to force it to be interpreted as a string](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=R+7QVSBzMymkbz5KIGknLjY=&input=MTU0NzIzMzg2Njc0NA==).
- Japt v1.4.5 is used because Japt doesn't have a constant for `17` and from v1.4.6 on [trying to insert something at the first index past the end of a string results in it being inserted *at* the end of the string](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=R+7QVSBzMymkbz5KIGkuQQ==&input=MTU0NzIzMzg2Njc0NA==) (`A` is the Japt constant for `10`) whereas prior to v1.4.6 [it immediately wraps back to the beginning of the string](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=R+7QVSBzMymkbz5KIGkuQQ==&input=MTU0NzIzMzg2Njc0NA==).

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 65 bytes

```javascript
n=>'101010.1010'.replace(i=/\d/g,x=>new Date(n).toJSON()[i=x-~i])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k7d0AAE9UCEul5RakFOYnKqRqatfkyKfrpOha1dXmq5gktiSapGnqZeSb5XsL@fhmZ0pm2Fbl1mrOb/5Py84vycVL2c/HSNNA0DTU0uVBFDUxNzI2NjCzMzcxMTDFmQuXp5@eUampqa/wE)

#### How?

We initialize the pointer \$i\$ to a non-numeric value (coerced to \$0\$) and then add alternately \$2\$ and \$1\$ to it to pick the relevant characters from the ISO-8601 conversion of the input timestamp.

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ
  ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 66 bytes

```javascript
n=>'235689.BCEF'.replace(/\w/g,x=>new Date(n).toJSON()[+`0x${x}`])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k7dyNjUzMJSz8nZ1U1dryi1ICcxOVVDP6ZcP12nwtYuL7VcwSWxJFUjT1OvJN8r2N9PQzNaO8GgQqW6ojYhVvN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaBpiYXqoihqYm5kbGxhZmZuYkJhizIaL28/HINTU3N/wA)

#### How?

Once the input timestamp is converted in ISO-8601 format, all required characters can be accessed with a single hexadecimal digit.

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ
  ↓↓ ↓↓ ↓↓ ↓↓ ↓↓
0123456789ABCDEF
```

Comment: Wow. Just, wow.

Comment: 64 bytes: `n=>'235689.11121415'.replace(/1?\w/g,x=>new Date(n).toJSON()[x])`

Comment: @tsh Nice! I was not expecting the decimal format to be shorter. You may want to post this as a separate answer.

Answer (score 7):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 29 bytes

```bash
date -d@${1::-3} +%y%m%d.%H%M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PyWxJFVBN8VBpdrQykrXuFZBW7VSNVc1RU/VQ9X3////hqYm5kbGxhZmZuYmJgA)

Answer (score 7):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>40</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to Luis felipe*
*-1 byte thanks to Jo King*

```php
<?=date('ymd.hi',$argv[1]/1e3);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42JbEkVUO9MjdFLyNTXUclsSi9LNowVt8w1VjT@v///4amJuZGxsYWZmbmJiYA)

Simple naive answer. PHP's `date` function takes a format string and an integer timestamp. Input from cli arguments, which is a string by default, then `/1e3` because `date` expects second-precise timestamps. This also coerces the string to a number.

Comment: Nice answer! It's a tad shorter if the language has date formatting, yes :)

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42JbEkVUO9MjdFLyNTXUclsSi9LNowVt/QwMBA0/r///@GpibmRsbGFmZm5iYmAA) you dont need to cast to integer since `"2"/1` will cast automatically the string

Comment: ah of course, I added intval before realising I needed `/1000`, and didn't think that I mihgt not need it afterwards :P

Comment: @JoKing ah nice one, thanks

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```powershell
"{0:yyMMdd.HHmm}"-f(Date 1/1/1970).AddSeconds("$args"/1e3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6nawKqy0tc3JUXPwyM3t1ZJN03DJbEkVcFQHwgtzQ009RxTUoJTk/PzUoo1lFQSi9KLlfQNU401////b2hqYm5kbGxhZmZuYgIA)

Gets the `Date` of `1/1/1970` (defaults to 00:00:00am), then `Add`s the appropriate number of `Seconds`. Passes that to the `-f`ormat operator, which correctly formats the datetime.

Probably culture-dependent. This works on TIO, which is `en-us`.

*-1 byte thanks to shaggy.*

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 28 bytes

*Thanks to [@skiilaa](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84948/skiilaa) for a correction in the output format.*

```
864e5/719529+'YYmmDD.HHMM'XO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38LMJNVU39zQ0tTIUls9MjI318VFz8PD11c9wv//f0NTE3MjY2MLMzNzExMA)

#### Explanation

MATL, like MATLAB, defines date/time numbers as the (possibly non-integer) number of days since time 00:00 of the reference "date" 0-Jan-0000.

Thus we take the input, divide it by 86400000 (number of milliseconds in one day), add 719529 (number of days from MATL's reference to UNIX reference), and convert to the desired format 'YYmmDD.HHMM'.

Answer (score 4):

## GNU AWK, <s>34</s> 33 characters

```awk
$0=strftime("%y%m%d.%H%M",$0/1e3)
```

(`strftime()` is GNU extension, will not run in other AWK implementations.)

Thanks to:

- [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) for suggesting [E-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation) (-1 character)

Sampler run:

```
bash-4.4$ awk '$0=strftime("%y%m%d.%H%M",$0/1e3)' <<< 1547233866744
190111.2111
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcC2uKQorSQzN1VDSbVSNVc1RU/VQ9VXSUfFQN8w1Vjz/39DUxNzI2NjCzMzcxMTAA)

Comment: Thank you, @JoKing. Unfortunately E-notation is not really my friend so I always forget it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>111 89</s>  87 bytes

```perl6
{~DateTime.new($_/Ⅿ,:formatter{"{(.year%Ⅽ,.month,.day).fmt('%02d','')}.{(.hour,.minute).fmt('%02d','')}"})}
```

[Try it (111)](https://tio.run/##Zc3BCoIwGADgu08xLJvCWE5Ns@jWI3SPob8oNBdzFkPs5uNE7@SLLOna/YPvDuqW2r4D9EhpcXQcYdCmkCWgkx1eZ67h0gigLTz99XU7Tx9yqKQSXGtQgzv41ABX3jy9CRWy1TWhJTcBrYT2sRdGJSYYByNdYC17taCm7TX8AXcMRttxg3412yVZFMf7NM2SBK0Qy0PGGGU5Y/YL)

```perl6
{TR/-//}o{S/..//}o{.yyyy-mm-dd~'.'~(.hour,.minute).fmt('%02d','')}o{DateTime.new($_/Ⅿ)}
```

[Try it (89)](https://tio.run/##HY3LCoJAFED3fsVAj1HQO161MYl2fUG5D3FuJDQaPgoR3fU9/VM/MolndTaH86T6IU3XEHtJyA@WpXu2zStF7GiG9Cw8IcZquAiARaCf8bT2lJo48MmGe9XVLuii7Fpy4KZbm2/8QHGXc2cOTllLaaEJSnrb66v4fb7OaJqsZ8sEd1EchOFeyjiK2Iph4iMiYIJo/g)

```perl6
{TR/- //}o{S/..//}o{.yyyy-mm-dd~'.'~(.hour,.minute).fmt('%02d')}o{DateTime.new($_/Ⅿ)}
```

[Try it (87)](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszcWVW6mglpyfkqpg@786JEhfV0Ffvza/OlhfTw/M0KsEAt3cXN2UlDp1PfU6Db2M/NIiHb3czLzSklRNvbTcEg11VQOjFHVNoGqXxJLUkMzcVL281HINlXj9R63rNWv/FydWKoCtMDQ1MTcyNrYwMzM3MVFQVjC0NDA0NNQztDQ0/A8A)

### Explanation:

The `o` infix operator takes two functions and creates a composite function. The rightmost one gets called first, and the one to the left gets called with its result.

Basically we use 4 block lambdas to generate a single lambda.

Which is not much different to how a WhateverCode lambda like `* + *` gets created.

---

Divide by 1000 and use that to create a DateTime object.

```perl6
{DateTime.new($_/Ⅿ)} # Ⅿ is ROMAN NUMERAL ONE THOUSAND (3 bytes)
```

The result gets used by:

```perl6
{
   .yyyy-mm-dd # 2019-01-11

   ~ '.' ~     # str concatenation with '.'

   ( .hour, .minute ).fmt('%02d') # add leading 0s (returns List)
}
```

That leaves us with a string like `2019-01-11.19 11`

We need to remove the first two digits

```perl6
{S/..//}
```

We also need to remove `-` and

```perl6
{TR/- //}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 64 bytes

```python
lambda s:strftime('%y%m%d.%H%M',gmtime(s/1e3))
from time import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqrikKK0kMzdVQ121UjVXNUVP1UPVV10nPRcsWKxvmGqsqcmVVpSfqwASUcjMLcgvKtH6X1CUmVeikKaRmVdQWqKhqfnf0NTE3MjY2MLMzNzEBAA)

The input is considered to be in UTC.

Comment: Just as something I've been a bit confused on, is the only reason that the `lambda` comes before the `import` because it works better for TIO's header?

Comment: @NeilA. Yes. The import can go either before or after, the contents of the lambda aren't checked for `NameError`s before it's called.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```r
format(as.POSIXct(scan()/1e3,,'1970-1-1'),'%y%m%d.%H%M')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/KDexRCOxWC/AP9gzIrlEozg5MU9DU98w1VhHR93Q0txA11DXUF1TR121UjVXNUVP1UPVV13zv6GpibmRsbGFmZm5icl/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (32-bit, little endian), 67 bytes

```c
f(t,s)long long t;{t/=1e3;strftime(s,12,"%y%m%d.%H%M",gmtime(&t));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYlBC8IgGEDP26@QgaHgCnVtgXTv0i@IDmLTBtNi39chxv56Vrs8Hu@5OjiXs2cogI@PFMgKNDPujrLXBnDyOMSegZBKVPRNI71t6YmeKxHiejbIuVnykJBEOyTGyVwW7m4nAheprqYsPJP7plNaH9q2axpBgP/q84XA/rbkj/OjDZDrqNUX)

On an ILP64 platform, the following **55 byte** version should work:

```c
f(t,s){t/=1e3;strftime(s,12,"%y%m%d.%H%M",gmtime(&t));}
```

Comment: What's the extra `s` argument you're taking for?

Comment: @Shaggy The `s` is for the output string.

Comment: It looks like you're initiating it outside the function; do we have a meta consensus that allows C to do that?

Comment: @Shaggy I'm not sure what "consensus" means exactly but here's the relevant [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16958/can-we-expect-out-arguments-to-be-allocated).

Comment: With "32-bit,", why `long long` instead of `long` or `int32_t`, `int64_t`, `time_t`? IAC, all shorter than `long long`.

Comment: @chux `long long` doesn't require to include a header file and a 32-bit type wouldn't be large enough for the input.

Comment: Hmm I was thinking, "32-bit, little endian" allowed `I32LP64` and `t` passed as at least `long`.  UV for the nice effort.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6, <s>76</s> 66 bytes

```
x=>new Date(x).toJSON().slice(2,16).replace(/\D/g,a=>a>'S'?'.':'')
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##DcexDoMgEADQX@l2kChGpWiaQBenDu3g2uWkp7EhYIS0/j3t294bPxjtvm6pnHAiV/rwojzrfGjj6XsaMBE7uEjhNj7ujIvoVkusKWrFxU6bw/@q51AtBWqDBka4goALAM82@BgcCRcWNrP6LLumbXulOik5zz8)

-10 bytes thanks to Shaggy!

---

```js
x // timestamp
=>
new Date(x) // date object from timestamp
.toJSON() // same as .toISOString()
.slice(2,16) // cut off excess
.replace(/\D/g, // match all non-digits
a // a is matched character
=>
a>'S'?'.' // if a is T (bigger than S is shorter) replace it with .
:''       // if it's not T, replace it with nothing
          // this way the dashes get removed and the dot gets put in the right place
) // end of replace
```

Comment: You may want to wait a day or so before answering your own questions next time.

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcG7DoIwFADQX3G7bQIlQAViUlycHHTQzUdyWy5E07SEVuXv6zlv/GIwy2uOuUZNNnd@oDSqtKre0W9zwEhs5SL64@V8YlyEjw5xYVVWSi4Wmi0aYsXteR8exZSh6lEpuMIeBOwAeDLeBW9JWD@xkZVb2VZ13TVNKyXn6Q8)

Comment: [Alternative 71 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYwxDsIwDAC/gjrZKrWUCiSWdGJiKAMvcBqLgqIYNaHt7wNZTnfLvXnlNC2vT@4cOwldVC@FbfF2gNnudoiyHa6cBTxS1tvjPgJS@rqUF9iPPSL02M5wrrhg21DzF2NqmhOWSWPSIBT0CQx1RFE3QMTyAw)

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, that's different enough for you to post yourself.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcexDoMgEADQX@l2kChGpWiaQBenDu3g2uWkp7EhYIS0/j3t294bPxjtvm6pnHAiV/rwojzrfGjj6XsaMBE7uEjhNj7ujIvoVkusKWrFxU6bw/@q51AtBWqDBka4goALAM82@BgcCRcWNrP6LLumbXulOik5zz8) to tie you with Arnauld.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>67</s> <s>61</s> 60 bytes

```cs
n=>$"{new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddTicks(n*10000):yyMMdd.HHmm}"
```

For reasons unknown to me, DateTime.UnixEpoch doesn't work.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5Ofl65TXFKUmZduV2H7P8/WTkWpOi@1XMElsSQ1JDM3VcPQ0txAx1DHUFPPMSUlJDM5u1gjT8vQAAg0rSorfX1TUvQ8PHJza5X@W3MFAM0p0ajQMDQ1MTcyNrYwMzM3MdHUtP4PAA)

Comment: It seems UnixEpoch is only present in.Net Core 2.1+

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>57</s> 50 bytes

```perl6
{TR:d/T:-/./}o{substr ~DateTime.new($_/1e3): 2,15}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OiTIKkU/xEpXX0@/Nr@6uDSpuKRIoc4lsSQ1JDM3VS8vtVxDJV7fMNVY00rBSMfQtPZ/cWKlQpqCoamJuZGxsYWZmbmJyX8A)

Takes the default stringification of a Datetime, in the format `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ` and modifies it to fit the output format. Perl 6 is in need of a date formatter method.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
                       Datetime.new($_/1e3) # Create a date time
                      ~                 # Stringify it to the format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ
                                        # e.g. 2019-01-11T19:11:06.744000Z
               substr                      : 2,15  # Take the middle 15 characters
 {TR:d/T  /./}o   # Then replace 'T' with '.'
        :-        # Then remove ':' and '-'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <strike>117</strike> 111 bytes

Thanks to @chux and @ceilingcat for the suggestions.

```c
#import<time.h>
*l;f(long t){t/=1e3;printf("%02d%02d%02d.%02d%02d",5[l=gmtime(&t)]%100,l[4]+1,l[3],l[2],l[1]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3NDoIwEITvPMWKkbRYlfKnScUXMRwIFmxSwNSNF8Oz11b0sLNfdiaz7a7Vzdhbu1bDYzJ4RjXI/f0SxFp0RE9jD0jfeKi4zMTDqBE7Em6S9Paf/R9CVlx11Q@@gERI6w1PEqaveb3lbmW1k9QLr6mYrWuCoVEj8dCYvmXtvTEQx45fFN4BwPJdOFosKQLHqiM@fuFLCACrJxqctD@/XDuDSDLgCRVf2@Xlqvp5EEWwiiWFjuDXn4PZWl7kxzTLTmV5zPMP)

Comment: `gmtime` is short than `localtime`

Answer (score 2):

## Twig, 25 characters

```twig
{{d[:-3]|date('ymd.hi')}}
```

This is a template. Call it by including it and pass the Unix time as parameter d.

Sample usage:

```
{{include('datetime.twig', {'d': 1547233866744})}}
```

[Try it on TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/rkyjd5)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 64 bytes

```javascript
n=>'2356891911121415'.replace(/1?./g,x=>new Date(n).toJSON()[x])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zcy9DoIwFEDh3adwozfR4u0fMBQXJwcdHI1DUwrRNC2BRnj7Gkfjer7kvMzbzHZ6jmkfYudyr3PQbcG4VHWDDSIyFCgLOrnRG@tIiUdaDrtVt8Et25NJjgSgKZ5v1wuB@/qAbGOYo3fUx4H05ACw@S0oRcU4r5WqhPjT75KGuBAAyB8)

Comment: [aw, so close](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i4vtVzBJbEkVSNPU68k3yvY309DU684JzM5VcNIx9BMU68otSAnEcjTj3HRT9epsLWrsFEPUbdXV7dS11PX/J@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrpGmYaCpyYUqYmhqYm5kbGxhZmZuYoIhC7JZLy@/XENTU/M/AA)

Comment: [also 64](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k7dyNjUzMJSz9DQ0MjQxNBUXa8otSAnMTlVQ9/QPiZFP12nwtYuL7VcwSWxJFUjT1OvJN8r2N9PQzO6Ilbzf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGgaYmF6qIoamJuZGxsYWZmbmJCYYsyEi9vPxyDU1Nzf8A)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 78 bytes

```java
n->new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd.HHmm").format(new java.util.Date(n))
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZA9b8IwEIZ3fsWJyR44UUihEqJThRgaFrpVHQ7HIKf2JUoutFHFb0@dEnWi6uL7eu/eR87pTJM8e@@Mp7qGlBx/jQAci62OZCzs@hJgL5XjExjlixhYr2L3MopPLSTOwA4Y1tDx5JHtB@TxKor9FNy7UHr7RGI3RRVI1Lht0zTLcLsNYazxeO3@LjXiPPZyxVp3q96hbA4@OgxG58JlECKmuiK9vgHpgbGtxQYsGsEyjsSzYjRq@qx/cP8U3N0ny9l8/rBYLJPkP/ENUo0nKy8uxEwPH3PpvgE)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->                       // Method with long parameter and String return-type
  new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd.HHmm")
                          //  Create the formatter
   .format(               //  Format the date to a String in this format and return it:
     new java.util.Date(  //   Create a new Date
      n))                 //   With the input-long as timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

## jq, 33 characters

(30 characters code + 3 characters command line option)

```
./1000|strftime("%y%m%d.%H%M")
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq -r './1000|strftime("%y%m%d.%H%M")' <<< 1547233866744
190111.1911
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/19P39DAwKCmuKQorSQzN1VDSbVSNVc1RU/VQ9VXSfP/f0NTE3MjY2MLMzNzE5P/ukUA)

Comment: You [don't need to count](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/42963) command-line flags anymore.

Comment: Oops. Good to know. Thank you @AdmBorkBork.

Comment: `1000` -> `1e3`

Answer (score 1):

## [ksh](http://www.kornshell.com/), 36 bytes

```sh
printf "%(%y%m%d.%H%M)T" $(($1/1e3))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy7O@P@/oCgzryRNQUlVQ7VSNVc1RU/VQ9VXM0RJQUVDQ8VQ3zDVWFPz////hqYm5kbGxhZmZuYmJgA)

Thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) for 15 bytes saved

Comment: The same in Bash would be just 35 characters: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUFJVUO1UjVXNUVP1UPVVzNESUElWsVQ39DAwCD2////hqYm5kbGxhZmZuYmJgA "Bash – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## MediaWiki, 46 bytes

```
{{#time:ymd.Hi|@{{#expr:floor({{{1}}}/1e3)}}}}
```