# Quotes around sequence of chars

Tags: code-golf

### Challenge

Your goal is to write a function that puts quotes around a sequence of capital letters in a string.

### So some examples (everything on the left (before function) and right (after function) are STRINGS):

`Hello the name's John Cena` -> `"H"ello the name's "J"ohn "C"ena`

`I got BIG OLD truck` -> `"I" got "BIG" "OLD" truck`

`[OLD, joe, SMOE]` ->`["OLD", joe, "SMOE"]`

`'BIG')` -> `'"BIG"')`

`fOOd` -> `f"OO"d`

`"78176&@*#dd09)*@(&#*@9a0YOYOYOYOYOYOOYOYOYOY28#@e` -> `"78176&@*#dd09)*@(&#*@9a0"YOYOYOYOYOYOOYOYOYOY"28#@e`

### Assumptions and Clarifications

- The sequence of capital letters can have a length of one (e.g. a string containing one character: H -> "H")
- You can assume there will be only a string inputted.

### Winning Criteria

Code golf, fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Great first question, well specified!

Comment: @xnor thx for the compliment

Comment: Quite similar to [Put in the quotes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199970/put-in-the-quotes).

Comment: What is the domain - is it ASCII only?

Comment: I'm having difficulties seeing that first test case... :P. Probably because the time is now!

Comment: @Lyxal word wordd can't see sumthing that ain't dere

Comment: I'm unable to see the words "John Cena"... Must be something to do with his phrase "you can't see me, my time is now". :P

Comment: @Lyxal exactly, me either Its the franchise, Boy, I'm shining now

Comment: @Lyxal btw who's answer do I choose?

Comment: Well, we usually don't choose anyone as the winner, as we just leave competitions infinitely open in case new answers become the winning answer. But if you want to choose someone, it's the answer with the shortest byte count. From the looks of things, that'd be the Gema answer, which is 8 bytes (correct at the time of posting this comment).

Comment: @Lyxal sounds good

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put in the quotes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199970/put-in-the-quotes)

Comment: @S.S.Anne what question do u speak of, this is a challenge

Comment: @Quora Sorry, it's duplicate flag boilerplate.

Comment: @S.S.Anne ah didn't know that, first time coding mb

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 15 bytes

```perl
s/[A-Z]+/"$&"/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP9pRNypWW19JRU1JP/3/f4/UnJx8hZKMVIW8xNxU9WIFr/yMPAXn1LxELk@F9PwSBSdPdwV/HxeFkqLS5GyuaCBTRyErP1VHIdjX3zWWSx0or67Jlebvn8KlZG5haG6m5qClnJJiYKmp5aChpqzlYJloEOmPgDCGkYWyQ@q//IKSzPy84v@6BTkA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
0.ø.γ.u}'"ý¦¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQO/wDr1zm/VKa9WVDu89tOzQiv//PVJzcvIVSjJSFfISc1PVixW88jPyFJxT8xIB)

```
0.ø              # surround input string with 0s
   .γ  }         # group characters by:
     .u          #  is uppercase?
        '"ý      # join groups with quotes
           ¦¨    # remove the first and last characters (0s)
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>32</s>  30 bytes

#### Using a reference to the last match

*Version suggested by @Grimmy*
*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/[A-Z]+/g,'"$&"')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzLDoIwFET3fsVNMZQiKLoQXWjwFR/RdOFKjYsGLvioraHo76MbY6JkNpM5J3MRT2Hi/HwvfKUTLNNBaQZD08zxLkWMTusw8vfHRivzKKnbhLIy1spoiU2pMyd1yAKl1FCcEJS4ITWw0icFE1SCMFb7kZeQ6QLGyznw9RSK/BFfK6zDG3pw0ejBdsNnxwqFvj8oqwAp58n/TEnYa4ddO3KtJAn6zI0c23Kjvgh2/JtP6fSsCClj5Qs)

## JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes

#### With a callback function

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/[A-Z]+/g,s=>`"${s}"`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzJCsIwFEX3fsUjFdPUOi4cFkqdcEDJwpWKYGhf6xATaaob8dtrNyJouZvLPYd7Fg9h/Ph0SypKB5iGvdT0@qYa400KH@3ablDZ7su1yM3mAyk@zYscWOprZbTEqtSRHdpkhlJqSI4ISlyRGljoo4IRKkEYK/zIc4h0AsP5FPhyDEl89y851i6DLpw1urBe8ck@R6HZB2U5IOQ8@J8paXca7VbJc6wgqHeZ49kly/G6or7h33xKs2N5SBlL3w)

Comment: amazing nice job

Comment: [32 with backrefs](https://tio.run/##bYzJCsIwFEX3fsUjlSapVasLh4VSJxxQsnCl4iK0r3WIiTTV369uRNByN5d7Dvcin9JG2fme17WJsUgGhR0MbSPDu5IRsiY7jOr7Y403U5@SaotQXkRGW6OwoUzKEkYWqJSB/ISg5Q2phZU5aZigloTzyo@8hNTkMF7OQaynkGeP6FpiHd7Qh4tBH7YbMTuWKPT9QXkJSISI/2dKur1Wt@OGnhPHQZ97IXMdL@zLYCe@@ZR2zwmRcl68AA)

Comment: Why not just [`$&`](https://tio.run/##bYzLDoIwFET3fsVNMZQiKLoQXWjwFR/RdOFKjYsGLvioraHo76MbY6JkNpM5J3MRT2Hi/HwvfKUTLNNBaQZD08zxLkWMTusw8vfHRivzKKnbhLIy1spoiU2pMyd1yAKl1FCcEJS4ITWw0icFE1SCMFb7kZeQ6QLGyznw9RSK/BFfK6zDG3pw0ejBdsNnxwqFvj8oqwAp58n/TEnYa4ddO3KtJAn6zI0c23Kjvgh2/JtP6fSsCClj5Qs)?

Answer (score 3):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 8 characters

```
<K>="$0"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ gema '<K>="$0"' <<< 'Hello the name’s John Cena'
"H"ello the name’s "J"ohn "C"ena
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/38bbzlZJxUDp/3@P1JycfIWSjFSFvMTcVPViBa/8jDwF59S8RC5PhfT8EgUnT3cFfx8XhZKi0uRsrmggU0chKz9VRyHY1981lksdKK@uyZXm75/CpWRuYWhupuagpZySYmCpqeWgoaas5WCZaBDpj4AwhpGFskMqAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.sub('([A-Z]+)',r'"\1"',s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqihVr7g0SUNdI9pRNypWW1Ndp0hdKcZQSV2nWJMrM7cgv6hEoSj1f0FRZl6JRpqGUkhGqkJeYm6qerGCV35GnoJzal6ikqbmfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r"%A+"`"$&"
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ciIlQSsiYCIkJiI&input=IkkgZ290IEJJRyBPTEQgdHJ1Y2si)

Answer (score 2):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>26</s> 21 bytes

Saved 5 bytes thanks to [Xcali](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72767/xcali)!!!

```
s/[[:upper:]]\+/"&"/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1g/OtqqtKAgtcgqNjZGW19JTUk//f//kIxUhbzE3FT1YgWv/Iw8BefUvEQA)

Comment: Using `&` cuts down on the byte count: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1g/OtqqtKAgtcgqNjZGW19JTUk//f//kIxUhbzE3FT1YgWv/Iw8BefUvEQA "sed – Try It Online")

Comment: @Xcali Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

Blatant port of RGS's Python answer. (I relized that I posted to the wrong challenge, whoops!)

```
:Q"([A-Z]+)""\"\\1\"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3ypQSSPaUTcqVltTSSlGKSbGMEbp/38lT4X0/BIFJ093BX8fF4WSotLkbCUA)

Comment: A shorter way to write the second string is `s[N\\1N`

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 11 bytes

```
[A-Z]+
"$&"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P9pRNypWm0tJRU3p/3@P1JycfIWSjFSFvMTcVPViBa/8jDwF59S8RC5PhfT8EgUnT3cFfx8XhZKi0uRsrmggU0chKz9VRyHY1981lksdKK@uyZXm75/CpWRuYWhupuagpZySYmCpqeWgoaas5WCZaBDpj4AwhpGFskMqAA)

I thought Retina has a shortcut for `[A-Z]` but apparently that only works in transliterations and not substitutions? Hmm...

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 34 bytes

```r
gsub("([A-Z]+)","'\\1'",scan(,''))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P724NElDSSPaUTcqVltTSUdJPSbGUF1Jpzg5MU9DR11dU/O/kkdqTk6@QklGqkJeYm6qerGCV35GnoJzal6iEpeSp0J6fomCk6e7gr@Pi0JJUWlyttJ/AA)

Simple use of Regular Expressions.

## 39 bytes

```r
cat(gsub('([A-Z]+)','"\\1"',scan(,'')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQfacYZjNKtugIfaAPQfuyhYkUZApq57f3Qs5aJXbF72TE9qbajpKTIJSyRhJRK8cEEec842is9ZBuA069hiLM/nbQGaewwAkun6CdBliXHlL49IP5Bw)

This method is the only way I can get the double quotes to work.

Comment: @JoKing Seems inconsequential to me. There was no specification on the type of quotes, but shockingly enough, the R code to switch it would be longer.

Answer (score 1):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 9 bytes

```
Í¨õ«©/"±"
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3DvoRWHtx5afWilvtKhjUr//3uk5uTkK5RkpCrkJeamqhcreOVn5Ck4p@YlcnF5KqTnlyg4ebor@Pu4KJQUlSZnc3FFA9k6Cln5qToKwb7@rrFcXOpAFeqaXFxp/v4pXFxK5haG5mZqDlrKKSkGlppaDhpqyloOlokGkf4ICGMYWSg7pAIA)**

This instructs Vim to replace all occurrences on all lines (`Í`)
...using the substitution `\(\u\)\+/"\1"`. Each `\x` may be replaced by `x` with the high-bit set, thus `\1` becomes `±`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>100</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>74</s></sup> 72 bytes

Saved <s>21</s> 23 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [S.S. Anne](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89298/s-s-anne)!!!

```c
t;u;f(int*s){for(t=1;*s;printf(s++),t=u)(u=*s<65|*s>90)^t&&putchar(34);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzJCsIwAETvfkVoISapQt26ECtFBVEEL16kIoQ0XRBTaZJT9durBcWLzGVmeDN8mHPetpoamqFSaqJwk1U10tGIEkXv9bvLkHIcPNCRwchERM292YOoRejii4bwbjQvWI0mU0yf7Y2VEuGml6G9dSwEkOwm@grsqkKClZDMwrT3ObXOsksduQV5pcFyuwGH/Rro2vDrf9APRr4HY2KnqRsmJE6gTeKQuafDT18zDuxYdMNn@wI)

Uses `wchar_t` strings for input.

Comment: @ceilingcat Wow! That's a great golf! Very readable in a golfy way: print quotes when we 're about to move in or out of caps. And of course that makes the `putchar` refactoring redundant - thanks! :-)

Comment: [-1 with widechar](https://tio.run/##NY09C8IwFAD3/opHh5qXKih@gMQ6qCCVgoujCCE0bZGmJXmZan97tIPjcQenFpVSIZDwQrPGEHc46M4yylaCO9F7UrW0jLs0xTllHpnPuDvsth/ujvslvihJ/tF6g2IMrWwMwyHSrIgfdQlGtuXMwa2rDZxLI2MUUW9/K83ip5loKnOoOoJTfoV7cQGyXr0nNYYv)

Comment: Try adding an L before the string to make it a widechar string.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Ah, that's a good one - thanks! :-)

Comment: @ceilingcat Huh, that's very interesting - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 10 bytes

Port of @Adám's answer.

```apl
[A-Z]+
"&"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/z/aUTcqVptLSU3p/3@P1JycfIWSjFSFvMTcVPViBa/8jDwF59S8RAUuT4X0/BIFJ093BX8fF4WSotLkbK5oIFNHISs/VUch2NffNZZLHSivrsmV5u@fwqVkbmFobqbmoKWckmJgqanloKGmrOVgmWgQ6Y@AMIaRhbJDKgA)

Comment: yo didn't realize ur question so similar my bad bro, got notified

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 31 bytes

```
0&?(:A$Z$•[⑻[|1⑼\",],|⑻[\",]0⑾,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fQM1ew8pRJUrlUcOi6EcTd0fXGD6auCdGSSdWpwbEBbEMHk3cp/P/v0dqpUJ6aWWxjkJ5Rr56sYKSV36qkr2Cl7@rgq@jr6MiAA)

But seriously, don't ask who Joe is.

Comment: wait, but, who's joe?

Comment: Joe mama! (I warned you not to ask! :P)

Comment: LLLLLLLLLLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL

Comment: Ha! Got'em! Haha XD lol!

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 64 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.chars.chunk{|c|c<c.downcase}.map{|u,c|u ??"+c*''+?":c}*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBDsIgEADAr2y4oFZ5gFE5eDH@Yl23IZEuTenGGODtqJfJLPr49BHO0A@XXLKjgMtflVepVOlE7pneQpi5uQnnUnVPVcF7M9DO2sGbI7VfWp91zTA6whg35sYxJlgDg@DENsM9BYErC5pt/wI)

Longer than the other Ruby solution, but one that doesn't use regex. I also love an excuse to use [`chunk`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/chunk).

This groups successive characters of the string depending on whether or not they're uppercase, and then surround the ones that *are* uppercase with `"`. I had to do the `downcase` check rather than checking with `upcase`, because otherwise non-character strings (spaces, punctuation, etc.) would also be considered uppercase letters.

### Golfy Tricks:

- `*''` instead of `.join`
- `<` instead of `!=`

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 22 bytes

```
gsub("[A-Z]+","\"&\"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/vbg0SUMp2lE3KlZbSUcpRkktRklJ8///kIxUhbzE3FT1YgWv/Iw8BefUvEQuT4X0/BIFJ093BX8fF4WSotLkbAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
Ｆ⁺Ｓ «ω✂"⁼№⪪α¹ω№αι≔ιω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYu7CgIxEEVr8xVDqgnEwnorXywLggvb2oSgMTgkax5uIX57TBCLC5dzOPqugvaKSrn5ADhSjji4OacpBesMCgkcuBDwZquxkoSL6P53IquvyC@cSzg@s6KIe5@bmMkmVBI2tV/qfrgCK0TrtzFa49A227FPKQMYn2A39HA@HSCFrB@srF/0BQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Port of my answer to the question linked by @manatwork in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
e€ØAŻIœṗj”"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/1UdOawzMcj@72PDr54c7pWY8a5ir9///fAyibr1CSkaqQl5ibql6s4OTpruCVn5Gn4JyalwgA)

A monadic link taking a string and returning a string.

Answer (score 0):

## perl -pE, 16 bytes

```
s/\p{Lu}+/"$&"/g
```

Unicode compliant, unlike the `s/[A-Z]+/"$&"/g` solution presented earlier.

Comment: Needs a `-CS` to [actually be unicode compliant](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP6ag2qe0VltfSUVNST/9/3@P1JycfIWSjFSFvMTcVPViBa/8jDwF59S8RC5PhfT8EgUnT3cFfx8XhZKi0uRsrmggU0chKz9VRyHY1981lksdKK@uyZXm75/CpWRuYWhupuagpZySYmCpqeWgoaas5WCZaBDpj4AwhpGFskMq1@GGoMPdh6cdXnl4/eHlh1ccWnxo6@FJev7/8gtKMvPziv/rOgcr6BbkAAA). Without the flag, [outputs garbage](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP6ag2qe0VltfSUVNST/9/3@P1JycfIWSjFSFvMTcVPViBa/8jDwF59S8RC5PhfT8EgUnT3cFfx8XhZKi0uRsrmggU0chKz9VRyHY1981lksdKK@uyZXm75/CpWRuYWhupuagpZySYmCpqeWgoaas5WCZaBDpj4AwhpGFskMq1@GGoMPdh6cdXnl4/eHlh1ccWnxo6@FJev7/8gtKMvPziv/rFuQAAA).

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.gsub(/([A-Z]+)/,'"\1"')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfpmCr8F/Xrri6WC@9uDRJQ18j2lE3KlZbU19HXSnGUElds/Z/QWlJsUKaXnJiTo6GkkdqTk6@QklGqkJeYm6qerGCV35GnoJzal6ikiYXikpPhfT8EgUnT3cFfx8XhZKi0uRsdCXqQFl1TSXN/wA)

A simple regex substitution.